# C++ division of unsigned shorts results in int

Tags: c++, int, division, unsigned, short

Why is the result of the division of two `unsigned short` of type `int` in C++? I have created an example which can easily be tested in e.g. http://cpp.sh/

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <typeinfo>

int main(){

  unsigned short a = 1;
  unsigned short b = 1;
  auto c = a/b;
  std::cout<<"result of dividing unsigned shorts is: "<<typeid(c).name()<<std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Implicit type conversion rules in C++ operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5563000/implicit-type-conversion-rules-in-c-operators) or [Why is unsigned short (multiply) unsigned short converted to signed int? [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33731158/why-is-unsigned-short-multiply-unsigned-short-converted-to-signed-int) or etc.

Comment: @underscore_d I think you are right. Thanks!

Comment: @underscore_d Good links, especially the second one. The question chosen to close as duplicate, however, only mentions the `unsigned short` promotion in passing, buried deep down into a couple of the later answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From Implicit conversions / Numeric promotions / [Integral promotion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Integral_promotion):

> *prvalues of small integral types (such as char) may be converted to prvalues of larger integral types (such as int). In particular*, ***arithmetic operators do not accept types smaller than int*** *as arguments, and integral promotions are automatically applied after lvalue-to-rvalue conversion, if applicable*.

---

[ *EDIT* ]   From the same page:

> *unsigned char, char8_t (since C++20) or* ***unsigned short can be converted to int if it can hold its entire value range***, *and unsigned int otherwise*

OP's case falls into the (highlighted) case since `sizeof int = 4 > 2 = sizeof unsigned int` on the target platform (according to the posted link). Had this *not* been the case (i.e. an `int` could *not* hold the entire range of `unsigned int` values, for example on platforms where `sizeof int == sizeof short`) then both operands would have been promoted to `unsigned int` by the integral promotion rules, and the result of the division would have been `unsigned int`, instead.

Comment: tl;dr: "because"