# wrap-around functionality in unsigned short

Tags: c++, integer-overflow

Whenever I run the code :

```
signed short ssh{-3};
unsigned short ussh{1};

std::cout << ussh + ssh << '\n'; // should be (65535-2+1) = 65534
```

I get the output as `-2` instead of 65534
while the same wrap-around functionality works well with the unsigned long and unsigned int.

Is unsigned short prohibited to perform wrap around or it is just promoted into int??

Comment: There are probably some dupes, here, but you can find the gist at [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Integral_promotion).

Comment: [Why is unsigned short (multiply) unsigned short converted to signed int?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33731370/12002570) and [Implicit type conversion rules in C++ operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5563000/implicit-type-conversion-rules-in-c-operators)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rules for integer promotion are very clear for C++.  Both values are going to be promoted to a type that has a range that can accept the values without change, which in your case is `int`.

Nothing is wrapping.

Answer (score 0):

By default, result of arithmetic operation would get promoted to type result can fit in. For bitwise and integer arithmetic operations it's an `int` or closest "bigger" type which can fit a result without altering it value .

Consider that your code is an equivalent of

```
{
   auto some_value = ussh + ssh;    // auto should be signed and an int at least
   std::cout << some_value << '\n';
}
```

Behavior you're looking for can be expressed in this or similar way:

```
// For complement of 2 it can be considered ssh being 
// cast to unsigned short
ussh += ssh;  
std::cout << ussh << '\n';
```