# What is the result of 'wrapping' a multiplication overflow?

Tags: c, integer-overflow

The bcache source [here](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/e0d072250a54669dce876d8ade70e417356aae74/drivers/md/bcache/writeback.c) contains the following line:

```
schedule_delayed_work(&dc->writeback_rate_update,
    dc->writeback_rate_update_seconds * HZ);
```

`writeback_rate_update_seconds` is defined as `unsigned int`, which [appears to be 32 bit](https://usrmisc.wordpress.com/2012/12/27/integer-sizes-in-c-on-32-bit-and-64-bit-linux/) on x86_64, and I am not sure what type `HZ` has but I believe the value is 1000 and assume it is 32-bit or less.

If I set `writeback_rate_update_seconds` to 2147483647, what value actually gets passed to `schedule_delayed_work`? The second parameter of `schedule_delayed_work` appears to be a `long`, but that won't mean the operands are promoted to long prior to the multiplication overflow, will it?

Comment: No, the value isn't promoted until after the multiplication is done, which uses the types of the original parameters.

Comment: Since it's `unsigned`, overflow wraps around using modular arithmetic.

Comment: @Barmar excuse my ignorance, but what does "wraps around using modular arithmetic" mean exactly? Does it mean the multiplication is done as if they were `long` but just the least significant 32 bits are returned?

Comment: also how do I find the type of HZ, if that is significant?

Comment: Look up modular arithmetic in Wikipedia. `HZ` is presumably a macro, just look at the macro definition and you should be able to tell what type it is.

Comment: "[retaining only the least significant bits of the result](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow)"

Comment: Yes, it's basically the same as that.

Comment: @Barmar I guess HZ is defined in `linux/sched/clock.h`, but I can't figure out what absolute path that relates to?

Comment: `/usr/include/linux/sched/clock/h`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int schedule_delayed_work( unsigned long param )
{
    printf("value: %lu\n", param);
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    unsigned int writeback_rate_update_seconds;
    unsigned int HZ;
    writeback_rate_update_seconds = 2147483647;
    HZ = 1000;
    schedule_delayed_work( writeback_rate_update_seconds * HZ );
    return 0;
}
```

You will get `4294966296` passed to the function.

If you change the function call to cast:

```
schedule_delayed_work( (unsigned long) writeback_rate_update_seconds * HZ );
```

... you will get `2147483647000` passed to the function.

I've not looked in the C standard to see what the standard behaviour is, but this was tested with:

```
Apple LLVM version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.38)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.7.0
```

Comment: Mind you, the behavior you see is for systems where `unsigned long` is 64 bits. With MSVC, `unsigned long` is 32 bits. This is allowed; `unsigned long long` is the only type which is guaranteed 64 bits.

Comment: thanks, and I get the same result if I tweak HZ to be signed (I think it's a macro and so effectively a literal `1000`, which is signed, but [gets typecast to unsigned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16966636/signed-unsigned-integer-multiplication) in the multiplication)

Answer (score 1):

If both operands fit in `unsigned int` (if `HZ` is constant `1000`, it is of type `int` and fits in `unsigned int`) they're promoted to `unsigned int`. With `unsigned` integers the overflow is well-defined; the resulting value is the value of calculation modulo (`UINT_MAX` plus one). That is, the maximum result is `UINT_MAX`; `UINT_MAX + 1` will result in 0, `UINT_MAX + 2` will result in 1 and so on.

The type of the receiver (here, the type of the argument that receives the result) doesn't matter at all. To avoid wraparounds, cast one of the arguments as a **wider integer type** (for example `unsigned long` is 64 bits in 64-bit Linux; or even better, use a fixed-width type such as `uint64_t`).