# A strange result occured in the following code(why input result 'b')

Tags: c++, c

```
int main(void)
    {
       int array[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
       int i = -1;
       if(i <= (sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0])) -2)
           printf("a\n");
       else
           printf("b\n");
       return(0);    
    }
```

I don't know why the IF expression is false.

Comment: Why do you think the opposite ?

Comment: explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/50605/signed-to-unsigned-conversion-in-c-is-it-always-safe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to compare a signed integer `int` and an unsigned integer `size_t`. 
Following C integer promotion rules, `i` gets promoted to an unsigned integer and therefore wraps to a very large number. When you compare that to the small value on the right side, the result is false.