# How is a negative character stored in memory?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i = 23;
    char c = -23;
    if (i < c)
        printf("Yes\n");
    else
        printf("No\n");
}
```

This segment of code executes the **else** block, but it executes the **if** block if we replace integer value with **unsigned int i = 23**.
Printing these values with `%x` results in

1. c=ffffffe9
2. i=17

My question here is how unsigned ints and char variables gets stored in memory?

Comment: In one of three ways stated here: http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.6.2

Comment: In addition to how the variables are stored in memory it is important how they are converted in expressions.

Comment: Keep in mind, this is likely to behave differently depending on compiler or compiler settings. `char` has implementation defined signedness; it could be signed or unsigned. If it's signed, then the behavior is defined from then on; `i < c` is definitely false. If it's unsigned, then I believe `c` would officially have undefined value (though on most two's complement systems, it would likely have the value `256 - 23`), making `i < c` true (both types would be promoted to `unsigned int` for the conversion). Point is, there is no guarantee that negative characters even exist.

Comment: @ShadowRanger `unsigned char c = -23;` is well defined.  Signed encoding used is irreverent here.

Comment: "How is a negative character stored in memory?
" --> Curious, _why_ is the encoding important?  It _value_, like any _signed integer_ type  is -23.  That should be enough.

Comment: Regarding unsigned int, see [Implicit type promotion rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46073295/implicit-type-promotion-rules)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you compare two different types, your compiler will perform a cast to the most suitable one. But in your case, there is no good solution: either you loose the sign, or the precision.

What is happening is that your compiler is promoting your `char` to `unsigned byte`.

You should check if your char is negative prior comparing it to an unsigned to prevent this from happening.

Answering what you are actually asking, a negative character is stored in memory using its [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement).

Answer (score 1):

This should help you understand it a bit better: [Signed to unsigned conversion in C - is it always safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50605/signed-to-unsigned-conversion-in-c-is-it-always-safe)

"The int data type is signed and has a minimum range of at least -32767 through 32767 inclusive. The actual values are given in limits.h as INT_MIN and INT_MAX respectively.

An unsigned int has a minimal range of 0 through 65535 inclusive with the actual maximum value being UINT_MAX from that same header file."

Enjoy! :)