# Error on casting unsigned int to float

Tags: c

For the following program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned int a = 10;
    unsigned int b = 20;
    unsigned int c = 30;
    float d = -((a*b)*(c/3));
    printf("d = %f\n", d);
    return 0;
}
```

It is very strange that output is

```
d = 4294965248.000000
```

When I change the magic number `3` in the expression to calculate d to `3.0`, I got correct result:

```
d = 2000.000000
```

If I change the type of a, b, c to `int`, I also got correct result.

I guess this error occurred by the conversion from `unsigned int` to `float`, but I do not know details about how the strange result was created.

Comment: If you use `int d`, you will get correct result. I think `float` and `double` can't accept `unsigned int` (`ULONG`).

Comment: the correct result should be `-2000`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you realize that you casting minus to `unsigned int` before assignment to `float`. If you run the below code, you will get highly likely `4294965296`

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned int a = 10;
    unsigned int b = 20;
    unsigned int c = 30;
    printf("%u", -((a*b)*(c/3)));

    return 0;
}
```

> The `-2000` to the right of your equals sign is set up as a signed
>   integer (probably 32 bits in size) and will have the hexadecimal value
>   `0xFFFFF830`. The compiler generates code to move this signed integer
>   into your unsigned integer `x` which is also a 32 bit entity. The
>   compiler assumes you only have a positive value to the right of the
>   equals sign so it simply moves all 32 bits into `x`. `x` now has the
>   value `0xFFFFF830` which is `4294965296` if interpreted as a positive
>   number. But the `printf` format of `%d` says the 32 bits are to be
>   interpreted as a signed integer so you get `-2000`. If you had used
>   `%u` it would have printed as `4294965296`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main()
{
    float d = 4294965296;
    printf("d = %f\n\n", d);
    return 0;
}
```

When you convert `4294965296` to `float`, the number you are using is long to fit into the fraction part. Now that some precision was lost. Because of the loss, you got `4294965248.000000` as I got.

> The IEEE-754 floating-point standard is a standard for representing
>   and manipulating floating-point quantities that is followed by all
>   modern computer systems.
>
> ```
> bit  31 30    23 22                    0
>      S  EEEEEEEE MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
> ```
>
> The bit numbers are counting from the least-significant bit. The first
>   bit is the sign (`0` for positive, `1` for negative). The following
>   `8` bits are the exponent in **excess-127** binary notation; this
>   means that the binary pattern `01111111 = 127` represents an exponent
>   of `0`, `1000000 = 128`, represents 1, `01111110 = 126` represents
>   `-1`, and so forth. The mantissa fits in the remaining `24` bits, with
>   its leading `1` stripped off as described above. [Source](http://www.cs.yale.edu/homes/aspnes/pinewiki/C(2f)FloatingPoint.html)

As you can see, when doing conversion `4294965296` to `float`, precision which is `00011000` loss  occurs.

```
11111111111111111111100 00011000 0  <-- 4294965296
11111111111111111111100 00000000 0  <-- 4294965248
```

Comment: ͏+͏1͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏ this is a helpful analysis, although I would mention that IEEE754 is not compulsory although highly probable.

Comment: @snr, thanks for your detailed explanation.   Is there any gcc options can give a warning to this dangerous conversion?

Comment: @gzh I don't know about any warnings. But this is not a dangerous conversion. It is the way the arithmetics work. It is always important to consider in which data type the calculation is done. A famous example `1/2*2` the result is `0` because `1/2`evaluates to `0`

Comment: @gzh I'm using CLion on macOS however same thing is true of ubuntu highly likely. Glance at the image --> https://i.imgur.com/GS8aroJ.gif

Answer (score 1):

Your whole calculation will be done [unsigned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50605/signed-to-unsigned-conversion-in-c-is-it-always-safe) so it is the same as

```
 float d = -(2000u);
```

`-2000` in `unsigned int` (assuming 32bits `int`) is `4294965295`

this gets written in your `float d`. But as `float` can not save this exact number it gets saved as `4294965248`.

As a rule of thumb you can say that float has a precision of 7 significant base 10 digits.

What is calculated is `2^32 - 2000` and then floating point precision does the rest.

---

If you instead use `3.0` this changes the types in your calculation as follows

```
float d = -((a*b)*(c/3.0));
float d = -((unsigned*unsigned)*(unsigned/double));
float d = -((unsigned)*(double));
float d = -(double);
```

leaving you with the correct negative value.

Comment: Actually you don't get the correct value; there is probably some rounding to `float`.

Comment: @Bathsheba I think `-2000` should not be a problem in single precision floating point.

Comment: indeed but don’t you see that one of the issues is an negation of an unsigned value?

Comment: @Bathsheba I do not understand what you mean. The answer has two parts. The first handles the unsigned part with the problem of the negation. The second part argues what happens with a double present in the formula. The double will make the result in the paranthesis double making a negation possible without any side effects. After that the result (-2000.0) gets assigned to `float d` which should have no problem handling that without error.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you use `-` on an `unsigned int`. The `-` inverts the bits of the number. Lets print some unsigned integers:

```
printf("Positive: %u\n", 2000);
printf("Negative: %u\n", -2000);

// Output:
// Positive: 2000
// Negative: 4294965296
```

Lets print the hex values:

```
printf("Positive: %x\n", 2000);
printf("Negative: %x\n", -2000);

// Output
// Positive: 7d0
// Negative: fffff830
```

As you can see, the bits are inverted. So the problem comes from using `-` on `unsigned int`, not from casting `unsigned int`to float.

Comment: What kind of universe has a 2's complement `unsigned` type ?!

Comment: `-` does not  inverts the bits of the number.  `~` inverts the bits.

Comment: Thanks. The reason is applying `-` on an `unsigned int`, have nothing to do with casting unsigned int to float. Maybe I should change the subject of this question.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, the issue is that you are trying to negate an unsigned number.  Most of the solutions already given have you do some form of casting to float such that the arithmetic is done on floating point types.  An alternate solution would be to cast the results of your arithmetic to `int` and then negate, that way the arithmetic operations will be done on integral types, which may or may not be preferable, depending on your actual use-case:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    unsigned int a = 10;
    unsigned int b = 20;
    unsigned int c = 30;
    float d = -(int)((a*b)*(c/3));
    printf("d = %f\n", d);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`-((a*b)*(c/3));` is all performed in *unsigned integer arithmetic*, **including** the unary negation. Unary negation is well-defined for an unsigned type: mathematically the result is modulo 2<sup>N</sup> where N is the number of bits in `unsigned int`. When you assign that large number to the `float`, you encounter some loss of precision; the result, due to its binary magnitude, is the nearest number to the `unsigned int` that divides 2048.

If you change 3 to 3.0, then `c / 3.0` is a `double` type, and the result of `a * b` is therefore converted to a `double` before being multiplied. This `double` is then assigned to a `float`, with the precision loss already observed.

Comment: "precision loss" applicability is unclear in OP's case.

Comment: @chux: It's hard to say what kind of loss it would be beyond our knowing what the intermediate result is (we know it's a 32 bit unsigned), and the scheme for the `float` on the platform (although we can conject it's IEEE754 due to the observed value). Which is why I was wooly in the answer. But I have now pointed out a property of the observed result.

Answer (score 0):

you need to cast the ints to floats

```
 float d = -((a*b)*(c/3));
```

to

```
float d = -(((float)a*(float)b)*((float)c/3.0));
```

Comment: Actually `-((a*b)*(c/3.f));` is sufficient.

Comment: Ah, yes. As long as there's one float everything else will be casted. I like to do it this way to remind myself what's really going on.

Comment: casted -> converted.