# why sizeof type compared with integer returns false

Tags: c, gcc

one strange behaviour I noticed in below code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main()
{
int x = sizeof(int) > -1;

bool z = sizeof(int);

printf("x is %d \t z is %d \n",x,z);
if(sizeof(int)>-1)
{
printf("true\n");
}
else
printf("false\n");
}
```

Why int x is zero when *sizeof(int) > -1* is true and the expected output should be 1.

Comment: Because `-1` when converted to an unsigned type becomes the maximum value that type can hold. You're comparing `sizeof (int) > 65535 /* or something like 2 billion */`. `sizeof (int) > -1` is **false**.

Comment: @pmg Something like four billion, right?

Comment: @unwind: right, only failed by 1 bit :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sizeof` operator yields not an `int` but `size_t` which is an unsigned integer type. When you compare a signed integer like -1 to an unsigned integer you will end up comparing the wrong values.

Do the following changes and the code will work as expected.

```
#include<stdio.h>

#include <stdbool.h>

int main()
{
    int x = (int)sizeof(int) > -1;

    bool z = sizeof(int);

    printf("x is %d \t z is %d \n",x,z);
    if((int)sizeof(int) > -1)
    {
        printf("true\n");
    }
    else
        printf("false\n");
}
```

Output:

```
x is 1   z is 1
true
```

Answer (score 4):

GCC compiler Warning say's :

> ```
> prog.c: In function 'main':
> prog.c:6:21: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: 'long unsigned int' and 'int' [-Wsign-compare]
>  int x = sizeof(int) > -1;
>                      ^
> prog.c:11:15: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: 'long unsigned int' and 'int' [-Wsign-compare]
>  if(sizeof(int)>-1)
> ```

So, you are comparing a `signed int` and an `unsigned long int`. When `-1` is converted to `unsigned long int` the result is the maximal possible `unsigned long int` value (same as `ULONG_MAX`).

**C $6.3.1.3, paragraph 2:**

> Otherwise, if the new type is `unsigned`, the value is converted by
>   repeatedly adding or subtracting one more than the maximum value that
>   can be represented in the new type until the value is in the range of
>   the new type.

For more information, read [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion).

Comment: Ho can I debug this issue , any idea so that I can look in deep further.

Comment: @torban you simply should avoid that in code. And watch out for that warning.

Comment: @torban There is nothing to debug. Most operators convert their operands to match. For integers `unsigned` always wins over `signed`. Google for "integer conversion rules in c".

Answer (score 0):

`sizeof` operator returns a type of `size_t`

The `size_t` type is an unsigned type. usually `unsigned int`

If you compare an `unsigned int` with `-1` then by the integer promotion rules ([Signed to unsigned conversion in C - is it always safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50605/signed-to-unsigned-conversion-in-c-is-it-always-safe/50632#50632)), both of them will be converted to unsigned.

So `-1` will be converted to 65535 and the equation `4>65535` will result in zero.

Answer (score -1):

Difference between signed and unsigned integer types (which includes `char`)  is that negative values are represented by most significant bit set to 1. On most platform the magnitude is represented by binary complement in that case. E.g. for `char`:

10000001:  -(1)0000000 * 01111111 = -127

We should take 00000001, substract 1 from it and invert all bits except sign to get the value.

Now, during comparison signed values treated as unsigned, if other argument is unsigned. There are historical and practical reasons for that, e.g. to avoid ambiguity in  character comparison when compiling legacy code. Traditionally all string in C were char* not unsigned char*.

10000001 as unsigned char equals to 129.

So, according to this program -1 is greater than 1.

```
#include <iostream>

int a = -1;
unsigned int b = 1;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    if(b < a) std::cout << "The world is mad.\n";
    if(a > b) std::cout << "Yes, it is.\n";
    return 0;
}
```

You always should look out for warning about comparison as well as about "possible data loss". Those are very common source of bug in programs.