# Multiple inconsistent behavior of signed bit-fields

Tags: c, gcc, clang, language-lawyer, bit-fields

I have come across a strange behavior on signed bit-fields:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

struct S {
    long long a31 : 31;
    long long a32 : 32;
    long long a33 : 33;
    long long : 0;
    unsigned long long b31 : 31;
    unsigned long long b32 : 32;
    unsigned long long b33 : 33;
};

long long f31(struct S *p) { return p->a31 + p->b31; }
long long f32(struct S *p) { return p->a32 + p->b32; }
long long f33(struct S *p) { return p->a33 + p->b33; }

int main() {
    struct S s = { -2, -2, -2, 1, 1, 1 };
    long long a32 = -2;
    unsigned long long b32 = 1;
    printf("f31(&s)       => %lld\n", f31(&s));
    printf("f32(&s)       => %lld\n", f32(&s));
    printf("f33(&s)       => %lld\n", f33(&s));
    printf("s.a31 + s.b31 => %lld\n", s.a31 + s.b31);
    printf("s.a32 + s.b32 => %lld\n", s.a32 + s.b32);
    printf("s.a33 + s.b33 => %lld\n", s.a33 + s.b33);
    printf("  a32 +   b32 => %lld\n",   a32 +   b32);
    return 0;
}
```

Using Clang on OS/X, I get this output:

```
f31(&s)       => -1
f32(&s)       => 4294967295
f33(&s)       => -1
s.a31 + s.b31 => 4294967295
s.a32 + s.b32 => 4294967295
s.a33 + s.b33 => -1
  a32 +   b32 => -1
```

Using GCC on Linux, I get this:

```
f31(&s)       => -1
f32(&s)       => 4294967295
f33(&s)       => 8589934591
s.a31 + s.b31 => 4294967295
s.a32 + s.b32 => 4294967295
s.a33 + s.b33 => 8589934591
  a32 +   b32 => -1
```

The above output shows 3 types of inconsistencies:

- different behavior for different compilers;
- different behavior for different bit-field widths;
- different behavior for inline expressions and equivalent expressions wrapped in a function.

The C Standard has this language:

> **6.7.2 Type specifiers**
>
> ...
>
> Each of the comma-separated multisets designates the same type, except that for bit-fields, it is implementation-defined whether the specifier `int` designates the same type as `signed int` or the same type as `unsigned int`.

Bit-fields are notoriously broken in many older compilers...
Is the behavior of Clang and GCC conformant or are these inconsistencies the result of one or more bugs?

Comment: You might want to take a step back, and just print the value of the six bit fields.

Comment: The code also has two warnings about mismatched arguments and format specifiers in the `printf`s. Until those are fixed, the code has undefined behavior, and is therefore allowed to do anything.

Comment: [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/4PAAnE) `gcc` looks like is masking every calculation on `long long : 33` bit-fields with a `2<<33-1` mask before and after calculation. `clang` just sign-extends `a33` and uses `rax` to calculate it - `clang` doesn't mask it with `2<<33-1`. I don't know if this is correct - should be a `long long : 33` bitfield promoted to `long long` or could be promoted to some implementation supported "__uint33_t"` type.

Comment: One issue that's confusing this is that you're ignoring the warnings about incompatible arguments for your format specifiers.   You need to cast the results of your inline additions to `long long` to get consistent results in the 4th, 5th, and 6th `printf` calls, e.g. `(long long) (s.a31 + s.b31)`  Fixing this gives consistent results for the function calls vs. the inline computations, at least with `gcc`.

Comment: The compiler behavior seems unintuitive to me.  One thing I noticed is that, with `gcc`, `sizeof(s.a31 + 0)` and `sizeof(s.a32 + 0)` are both 4 on my system, but `sizeof(s.a33 + 0)` is 8.  I would have thought they would all be unpacked into `long long` and have size 8, but apparently not.

Comment: * Do not use bit field types other than `signed int`, `unsigned`, `_Bool`.  Anything else is trouble.  "A bit-field shall have a type that is a qualified or unqualified version of _Bool, signed
int, unsigned int, or some other implementation-defined type." C11 §6.7.2.1 5

Comment: There is also likely implementation-defined behaviour in the `return` statement: the operand being returned may be an unsigned value out of range for `long long`

Answer (score 2):

> Is the behavior of Clang and GCC conformant or are these inconsistencies the result of one or more bugs?

I think it's most likely the fault is in your code, tbh. According to [6.7.2.1p5](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.2.1p5):

> A bit-field shall have a type that is a qualified or unqualified version of _Bool, signed int, unsigned int, or some other implementation-defined type.

There's no mention of `long long` here, so we can't necessarily treat this code as conformant to begin with. It seems that some compilers have documented support (for example, [some ARM clang targets](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/101754/0618/Supporting-Information-Appendix/Standard-C-Implementation-Definition/Structures--unions--enumerations--and-bitfields)), whereas others are happy to let the behaviour be undefined (for example, [gcc manuals don't appear to list `long long`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Structures-unions-enumerations-and-bit-fields-implementation.html#Structures-unions-enumerations-and-bit-fields-implementation) in the category of "Allowable bit-field types other than _Bool, signed int, and unsigned int (C99 and C11 6.7.2.1)").

Furthermore, according to [6.3.1.1p2](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.1p2):

> The following may be used in an expression wherever an int or unsigned int may be used:
>
> - An object or expression with an integer type (other than int or unsigned int) whose integer conversion rank is less than or equal to the rank of int and unsigned int.
> - A bit-field of type _Bool, int, signed int, or unsigned int.
>
> If an int can represent all values of the original type (as restricted by the width, for a bit-field), the value is converted to an int; otherwise, it is converted to an unsigned int.

In other words, it isn't simply enough for the compiler to support these types of bit-fields, but also to have appropriate type conversions so that the expressions are converted properly. Specifically, this code looks *utterly terrifying*, because `%lld` tells `printf` to expect `long long int`, whereas I think you may only be passing an `int` (or `unsigned`, perhaps):

> ```
> printf("s.a31 + s.b31 => %lld\n", s.a31 + s.b31);
> printf("s.a32 + s.b32 => %lld\n", s.a32 + s.b32);
> printf("s.a33 + s.b33 => %lld\n", s.a33 + s.b33);
> printf("  a32 +   b32 => %lld\n",   a32 +   b32);
> ```

I figured I'd sign off quoting my expected result of this *hairy looking code* above:

> If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is undefined.<sup>282)</sup> If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined.

-- C11/7.21.6.1p9

Comment: The type of the bitfield is a Constraint, so if the compiler didn't define the behaviour of `long long` bitfields, a diagnostic message is compulsory. Assuming OP didn't see a diagnostic we could conclude that the implementation does define `long long` bitfields . Which means the implementation must document this behaviour else it's nonconforming . In particular, it's relevant how the compiler defines the integer conversion rank of these bitfields .

Comment: @M.M ok you can see the link to the gcc manual that doesn't document `long long` bitfields... Any implementation-defined behaviour must be documented here, but it isn't, so would you agree that the behaviour is probably undefined?

Comment: The behaviour is implementation-defined, and if the compiler does not document it, then the compiler is non-conforming .

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look to the proposed code which works correctly and as expected.

For the practical purpose, I would suggest, just make sure that

- compatible types are added,
- correct types are returned and
- correct types are in the printf statement.

That's it.

For more information, see also Ref.[1] and [2], below.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct S {
    long long a31 : 31;
    long long a32 : 32;
    long long a33 : 33;
    
    unsigned long long b31 : 31;
    unsigned long long b32 : 32;
    unsigned long long b33 : 33;
};

long long f31(struct S *p) { return ((long long)p->a31 + (long long)p->b31); }
long long f32(struct S *p) { return ((long long)p->a32 + (long long)p->b32); }
long long f33(struct S *p) { return ((long long)p->a33 + (long long)p->b33); }

int main() {
    struct S s = { -2, -2, -2, 1, 1, 1 };
    long long a32 = -2;
    unsigned long long b32 = 1;
    
    printf("p->a31       => %lld\n", (long long)(s.a31));
    printf("p->a32       => %lld\n", (long long)(s.a32));
    printf("p->a33       => %lld\n", (long long)(s.a33));
    
    printf("p->b31       => %lld\n", (long long)(s.b31));
    printf("p->b32       => %lld\n", (long long)(s.b32));
    printf("p->b33       => %lld\n", (long long)(s.b33));
    
    
    printf("f31(&s)       => %lld\n", (long long)(f31(&s)));
    printf("f32(&s)       => %lld\n", (long long)(f32(&s)));
    printf("f33(&s)       => %lld\n", (long long)(f33(&s)));
    printf("s.a31 + s.b31 => %lld\n", ((long long)s.a31 + (long long)s.b31));
    printf("s.a32 + s.b32 => %lld\n", ((long long)s.a32 + (long long)s.b32));
    printf("s.a33 + s.b33 => %lld\n", ((long long)s.a33 + (long long)s.b33));
    printf("  a32 +   b32 => %lld\n", (long long) (a32 +   b32));
    return 0;
}
```

```
p->a31       => -2
p->a32       => -2
p->a33       => -2
p->b31       => 1
p->b32       => 1
p->b33       => 1
f31(&s)       => -1
f32(&s)       => -1
f33(&s)       => -1
s.a31 + s.b31 => -1
s.a32 + s.b32 => -1
s.a33 + s.b33 => -1
  a32 +   b32 => -1
```

References

[1] [Signed to unsigned conversion in C - is it always safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50605/signed-to-unsigned-conversion-in-c-is-it-always-safe)

[2] https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bit-fields-c/
"We cannot have pointers to bit field members as they may not start at a byte boundary."

Comment: "as expected" - by whom? The original code adds unsigned and signed variants of the same type, so OP may be expecting implicit conversion to unsigned for the result(e.g. as in `-1L + 2UL`). Your suggested takes away that aspect of the question.