# Inconsistent truncation of unsigned bitfield integer expressions between C++ and C in different compilers

Tags: c++, c, language-lawyer, bit-fields, truncation

**Edit 2**:

I was debugging a strange test failure when a function previously residing in a C++ source file but moved into a C file verbatim, started to return incorrect results. The MVE below allows to reproduce the problem with GCC. However, when I, on a whim, compiled the example with Clang (and later with VS), I got a different result! I cannot figure out whether to treat this as a bug in one of the compilers, or as manifestation of undefined result allowed by C or C++ standard. Strangely, none of the compilers gave me any warnings about the expression.

The culprit is this expression:

```
ctl.b.p52 << 12;
```

Here, `p52` is typed as `uint64_t`; it is also a part of a union (see `control_t` below). The shift operation does not lose any data as the result still fits into 64 bits. However, then GCC decides to truncate the result to 52 bits **if I use C compiler**! With C++ compiler, all 64 bits of result are preserved.

To illustrate this, the example program below compiles two functions with identical bodies, and then compares their results. `c_behavior()` is placed in a C source file and `cpp_behavior()` in a C++ file, and `main()` does the comparison.

Repository with the example code: https://github.com/atakua/c-cpp-bitfields

Header common.h defines a union of 64-bit wide bitfields and integer and declares two functions:

```
#ifndef COMMON_H
#define COMMON_H

#include <stdint.h>

typedef union control {
        uint64_t q;
        struct {
                uint64_t a: 1;
                uint64_t b: 1;
                uint64_t c: 1;
                uint64_t d: 1;
                uint64_t e: 1;
                uint64_t f: 1;
                uint64_t g: 4;
                uint64_t h: 1;
                uint64_t i: 1;
                uint64_t p52: 52;
        } b;
} control_t;

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

uint64_t cpp_behavior(control_t ctl);
uint64_t c_behavior(control_t ctl);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif // COMMON_H
```

The functions have identical bodies, except that one is treated as C and another as C++.

c-part.c:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include "common.h"
uint64_t c_behavior(control_t ctl) {
    return ctl.b.p52 << 12;
}
```

cpp-part.cpp:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include "common.h"
uint64_t cpp_behavior(control_t ctl) {
    return ctl.b.p52 << 12;
}
```

main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "common.h"

int main() {
    control_t ctl;
    ctl.q = 0xfffffffd80236000ull;

    uint64_t c_res = c_behavior(ctl);
    uint64_t cpp_res = cpp_behavior(ctl);
    const char *announce = c_res == cpp_res? "C == C++" : "OMG C != C++";
    printf("%s\n", announce);

    return c_res == cpp_res? 0: 1;
}
```

GCC shows the difference between the results they return:

```
$ gcc -Wpedantic main.c c-part.c cpp-part.cpp

$ ./a.exe
OMG C != C++
```

However, with Clang C and C++ behave identically and as expected:

```
$ clang -Wpedantic main.c c-part.c cpp-part.cpp

$ ./a.exe
C == C++
```

With Visual Studio I get the same result as with Clang:

```
C:\Users\user\Documents>cl main.c c-part.c cpp-part.cpp
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.00.24234.1 for x64
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

main.c
c-part.c
Generating Code...
Compiling...
cpp-part.cpp
Generating Code...
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.00.24234.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

/out:main.exe
main.obj
c-part.obj
cpp-part.obj

C:\Users\user\Documents>main.exe
C == C++
```

I tried the examples on Windows, even though the original problem with GCC was discovered on Linux.

Comment: bit-fields are notoriously bogus for large widths. I came across similar issues in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58846584/multiple-inconsistent-behavior-of-signed-bit-fields

Comment: @chqrlie I read the [C `<<` operator](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.7p4) as **requiring** the truncation.

Comment: Please post a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example  . The current code has no `main.c` and probably causes undefined behaviour in several ways.    IMO it would be clearer to post a single-file MRE which produces different output when compiled with each compiler. Because C-C++ interop is not specified well by the standard . Also note that union aliasing causes UB in C++.

Comment: @M.M Right, it have slipped when I was posting the question. I have added it now, and also I think having a small repository with it might also be an idea

Comment: @M.M "IMO it would be clearer to post a single-file MRE which produces different output when compiled with each compiler. " I haven't thought about that as I was transforming my production code into something smaller, but it should be possible to reformulate the reproducer into a single file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C and C++ treat the types of bit-field members differently.

C 2018 6.7.2.1 10 says:

> A bit-field is interpreted as having a signed or unsigned integer type consisting of the specified number of bits…

Observe this is not specific about the type—it is some integer type—and it does not say the type is the type that was used to declare the bit-field, as in the `uint64_t a : 1;` shown in the question. This apparently leaves it open to the implementation to choose the type.

C++ 2017 draft n4659 12.2.4 [class.bit] 1 says, of a bit-field declaration:

> … The bit-field attribute is not part of the type of the class member…

This implies that, in a declaration such as `uint64_t a : 1;`, the `: 1` is not part of the type of the class member `a`, so the type is as if it were `uint64_t a;`, and thus the type of `a` is `uint64_t`.

So it appears GCC treats a bit-field in C as some integer type 32-bits or narrower if it fits and a bit-field in C++ as its declared type, and this does not appear to violate the standards.

Comment: I read the truncation in C as mandatory [per 6.5.7 4](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.7p4) (C18 wording is similar):  "The result of E1 << E2 is E1 left-shifted E2 bit positions; vacated bits are filled with zeros. If E1 has an unsigned type, the value of the result is E1 x 2E2 , reduced modulo one more than the maximum value representable in the result type."  `E1` in this case is a 52-bit bit-field.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: I see what you are saying. The type of an *n*-bit bit-field is “*n*-bit integer” (neglecting signedness for now). I was interpreting it as the type of an *n*-bit bit-field is some integer type, which the implementation chooses. Based solely on the wording in 6.7.2.1 10, I favor your interpretation. But a problem with that is that, given a `uint64_t a : 33` set to 2^33−1 in a structure `s`, then, in a C implementation with 32-bit `int`, `s.a+s.a` should yield 2^33−2 due to wrapping, but Clang produces 2^34−2; it apparently treats it as `uint64_t`.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: (More on the reasoning: In `s.a+s.a`, the usual arithmetic conversions would not change the type of `s.a`, since it is wider than `unsigned int`, so the arithmetic would be done in the 33-bit type.)

Comment: *but Clang produces 2^34−2; it apparently treats it as `uint64_t`.*  If that's a 64-bit compile, that seems to make Clang consistent with how GCC is treating 64-bit compiles by not truncating.  Does Clang treat 32- and 64-bit compiles differently?  (And it seems I just learned another reason to avoid bit fields...)

Comment: @AndrewHenle: Well, old Apple Clang 1.7 produces 2^32−2 (not 2^33−2; it lost a bit!) both with `-m32` and `-m64`, with a warning that the type is a GCC extension. With Apple Clang 11.0, I do not have libraries to run 32-bit code, but the generated assembly shows `pushl $3` and `pushl $-2` before calling `printf`, so I think that is 2^34−2. So Apple Clang is not differing between 32-bit and 64-bit targets but did change over time.

Comment: I think you misread "The bit-field attribute is not part of the type of the class member". The term "attribute" does not refer to the `: 1`

Comment: @M.M: What do you think it refers to?

Comment: @EricPostpischil see [class.bit]/1 where it says *attribute-specifier-seq*.  The thing after the colon is referred to as the *constant-expression*

Comment: @M.M: Yes, a bit-field declaration may also have attributes specified in an *attribute-specifier-seq*. Those are referred to in the text as the optional “*attribute-specifier-seq*”. I believe the text “bit-field attribute” refers to the “: *constant-expression*”. Note that other declarations also have an optional *attribute-specifier-seq* but do not have this text saying some attribute is not part of the type. So this “bit-field attribute” the text refers to does appear to be specific to bit-fields.

Answer (score 7):

Andrew Henle suggested a strict interpretation of the C Standard: the type of a bit-field is a a signed or unsigned integer type with exactly the specified width.

Here is a test that supports this interpretation: using the C1x `_Generic()` construction, I'm trying to determine the type of bit-fields of different widths. I had to define them with the type `long long int` to avoid warnings when compiling with clang.

Here is the source:

```c
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define typeof(X)  _Generic((X),                         \
                       long double: "long double",       \
                       double: "double",                 \
                       float: "float",                   \
                       unsigned long long int: "unsigned long long int",  \
                       long long int: "long long int",   \
                       unsigned long int: "unsigned long int",  \
                       long int: "long int",             \
                       unsigned int: "unsigned int",     \
                       int: "int",                       \
                       unsigned short: "unsigned short", \
                       short: "short",                   \
                       unsigned char: "unsigned char",   \
                       signed char: "signed char",       \
                       char: "char",                     \
                       _Bool: "_Bool",                   \
                       __int128_t: "__int128_t",         \
                       __uint128_t: "__uint128_t",       \
                       default: "other")

#define stype long long int
#define utype unsigned long long int

struct s {
    stype s1 : 1;
    stype s2 : 2;
    stype s3 : 3;
    stype s4 : 4;
    stype s5 : 5;
    stype s6 : 6;
    stype s7 : 7;
    stype s8 : 8;
    stype s9 : 9;
    stype s10 : 10;
    stype s11 : 11;
    stype s12 : 12;
    stype s13 : 13;
    stype s14 : 14;
    stype s15 : 15;
    stype s16 : 16;
    stype s17 : 17;
    stype s18 : 18;
    stype s19 : 19;
    stype s20 : 20;
    stype s21 : 21;
    stype s22 : 22;
    stype s23 : 23;
    stype s24 : 24;
    stype s25 : 25;
    stype s26 : 26;
    stype s27 : 27;
    stype s28 : 28;
    stype s29 : 29;
    stype s30 : 30;
    stype s31 : 31;
    stype s32 : 32;
    stype s33 : 33;
    stype s34 : 34;
    stype s35 : 35;
    stype s36 : 36;
    stype s37 : 37;
    stype s38 : 38;
    stype s39 : 39;
    stype s40 : 40;
    stype s41 : 41;
    stype s42 : 42;
    stype s43 : 43;
    stype s44 : 44;
    stype s45 : 45;
    stype s46 : 46;
    stype s47 : 47;
    stype s48 : 48;
    stype s49 : 49;
    stype s50 : 50;
    stype s51 : 51;
    stype s52 : 52;
    stype s53 : 53;
    stype s54 : 54;
    stype s55 : 55;
    stype s56 : 56;
    stype s57 : 57;
    stype s58 : 58;
    stype s59 : 59;
    stype s60 : 60;
    stype s61 : 61;
    stype s62 : 62;
    stype s63 : 63;
    stype s64 : 64;

    utype u1 : 1;
    utype u2 : 2;
    utype u3 : 3;
    utype u4 : 4;
    utype u5 : 5;
    utype u6 : 6;
    utype u7 : 7;
    utype u8 : 8;
    utype u9 : 9;
    utype u10 : 10;
    utype u11 : 11;
    utype u12 : 12;
    utype u13 : 13;
    utype u14 : 14;
    utype u15 : 15;
    utype u16 : 16;
    utype u17 : 17;
    utype u18 : 18;
    utype u19 : 19;
    utype u20 : 20;
    utype u21 : 21;
    utype u22 : 22;
    utype u23 : 23;
    utype u24 : 24;
    utype u25 : 25;
    utype u26 : 26;
    utype u27 : 27;
    utype u28 : 28;
    utype u29 : 29;
    utype u30 : 30;
    utype u31 : 31;
    utype u32 : 32;
    utype u33 : 33;
    utype u34 : 34;
    utype u35 : 35;
    utype u36 : 36;
    utype u37 : 37;
    utype u38 : 38;
    utype u39 : 39;
    utype u40 : 40;
    utype u41 : 41;
    utype u42 : 42;
    utype u43 : 43;
    utype u44 : 44;
    utype u45 : 45;
    utype u46 : 46;
    utype u47 : 47;
    utype u48 : 48;
    utype u49 : 49;
    utype u50 : 50;
    utype u51 : 51;
    utype u52 : 52;
    utype u53 : 53;
    utype u54 : 54;
    utype u55 : 55;
    utype u56 : 56;
    utype u57 : 57;
    utype u58 : 58;
    utype u59 : 59;
    utype u60 : 60;
    utype u61 : 61;
    utype u62 : 62;
    utype u63 : 63;
    utype u64 : 64;
} x;

int main(void) {
#define X(v)  printf("typeof(" #v "): %s\n", typeof(v))
    X(x.s1);
    X(x.s2);
    X(x.s3);
    X(x.s4);
    X(x.s5);
    X(x.s6);
    X(x.s7);
    X(x.s8);
    X(x.s9);
    X(x.s10);
    X(x.s11);
    X(x.s12);
    X(x.s13);
    X(x.s14);
    X(x.s15);
    X(x.s16);
    X(x.s17);
    X(x.s18);
    X(x.s19);
    X(x.s20);
    X(x.s21);
    X(x.s22);
    X(x.s23);
    X(x.s24);
    X(x.s25);
    X(x.s26);
    X(x.s27);
    X(x.s28);
    X(x.s29);
    X(x.s30);
    X(x.s31);
    X(x.s32);
    X(x.s33);
    X(x.s34);
    X(x.s35);
    X(x.s36);
    X(x.s37);
    X(x.s38);
    X(x.s39);
    X(x.s40);
    X(x.s41);
    X(x.s42);
    X(x.s43);
    X(x.s44);
    X(x.s45);
    X(x.s46);
    X(x.s47);
    X(x.s48);
    X(x.s49);
    X(x.s50);
    X(x.s51);
    X(x.s52);
    X(x.s53);
    X(x.s54);
    X(x.s55);
    X(x.s56);
    X(x.s57);
    X(x.s58);
    X(x.s59);
    X(x.s60);
    X(x.s61);
    X(x.s62);
    X(x.s63);
    X(x.s64);

    X(x.u1);
    X(x.u2);
    X(x.u3);
    X(x.u4);
    X(x.u5);
    X(x.u6);
    X(x.u7);
    X(x.u8);
    X(x.u9);
    X(x.u10);
    X(x.u11);
    X(x.u12);
    X(x.u13);
    X(x.u14);
    X(x.u15);
    X(x.u16);
    X(x.u17);
    X(x.u18);
    X(x.u19);
    X(x.u20);
    X(x.u21);
    X(x.u22);
    X(x.u23);
    X(x.u24);
    X(x.u25);
    X(x.u26);
    X(x.u27);
    X(x.u28);
    X(x.u29);
    X(x.u30);
    X(x.u31);
    X(x.u32);
    X(x.u33);
    X(x.u34);
    X(x.u35);
    X(x.u36);
    X(x.u37);
    X(x.u38);
    X(x.u39);
    X(x.u40);
    X(x.u41);
    X(x.u42);
    X(x.u43);
    X(x.u44);
    X(x.u45);
    X(x.u46);
    X(x.u47);
    X(x.u48);
    X(x.u49);
    X(x.u50);
    X(x.u51);
    X(x.u52);
    X(x.u53);
    X(x.u54);
    X(x.u55);
    X(x.u56);
    X(x.u57);
    X(x.u58);
    X(x.u59);
    X(x.u60);
    X(x.u61);
    X(x.u62);
    X(x.u63);
    X(x.u64);

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the program's output compiled with 64-bit clang:

```
typeof(x.s1): long long int
typeof(x.s2): long long int
typeof(x.s3): long long int
typeof(x.s4): long long int
typeof(x.s5): long long int
typeof(x.s6): long long int
typeof(x.s7): long long int
typeof(x.s8): long long int
typeof(x.s9): long long int
typeof(x.s10): long long int
typeof(x.s11): long long int
typeof(x.s12): long long int
typeof(x.s13): long long int
typeof(x.s14): long long int
typeof(x.s15): long long int
typeof(x.s16): long long int
typeof(x.s17): long long int
typeof(x.s18): long long int
typeof(x.s19): long long int
typeof(x.s20): long long int
typeof(x.s21): long long int
typeof(x.s22): long long int
typeof(x.s23): long long int
typeof(x.s24): long long int
typeof(x.s25): long long int
typeof(x.s26): long long int
typeof(x.s27): long long int
typeof(x.s28): long long int
typeof(x.s29): long long int
typeof(x.s30): long long int
typeof(x.s31): long long int
typeof(x.s32): long long int
typeof(x.s33): long long int
typeof(x.s34): long long int
typeof(x.s35): long long int
typeof(x.s36): long long int
typeof(x.s37): long long int
typeof(x.s38): long long int
typeof(x.s39): long long int
typeof(x.s40): long long int
typeof(x.s41): long long int
typeof(x.s42): long long int
typeof(x.s43): long long int
typeof(x.s44): long long int
typeof(x.s45): long long int
typeof(x.s46): long long int
typeof(x.s47): long long int
typeof(x.s48): long long int
typeof(x.s49): long long int
typeof(x.s50): long long int
typeof(x.s51): long long int
typeof(x.s52): long long int
typeof(x.s53): long long int
typeof(x.s54): long long int
typeof(x.s55): long long int
typeof(x.s56): long long int
typeof(x.s57): long long int
typeof(x.s58): long long int
typeof(x.s59): long long int
typeof(x.s60): long long int
typeof(x.s61): long long int
typeof(x.s62): long long int
typeof(x.s63): long long int
typeof(x.s64): long long int
typeof(x.u1): unsigned long long int
typeof(x.u2): unsigned long long int
typeof(x.u3): unsigned long long int
typeof(x.u4): unsigned long long int
typeof(x.u5): unsigned long long int
typeof(x.u6): unsigned long long int
typeof(x.u7): unsigned long long int
typeof(x.u8): unsigned long long int
typeof(x.u9): unsigned long long int
typeof(x.u10): unsigned long long int
typeof(x.u11): unsigned long long int
typeof(x.u12): unsigned long long int
typeof(x.u13): unsigned long long int
typeof(x.u14): unsigned long long int
typeof(x.u15): unsigned long long int
typeof(x.u16): unsigned long long int
typeof(x.u17): unsigned long long int
typeof(x.u18): unsigned long long int
typeof(x.u19): unsigned long long int
typeof(x.u20): unsigned long long int
typeof(x.u21): unsigned long long int
typeof(x.u22): unsigned long long int
typeof(x.u23): unsigned long long int
typeof(x.u24): unsigned long long int
typeof(x.u25): unsigned long long int
typeof(x.u26): unsigned long long int
typeof(x.u27): unsigned long long int
typeof(x.u28): unsigned long long int
typeof(x.u29): unsigned long long int
typeof(x.u30): unsigned long long int
typeof(x.u31): unsigned long long int
typeof(x.u32): unsigned long long int
typeof(x.u33): unsigned long long int
typeof(x.u34): unsigned long long int
typeof(x.u35): unsigned long long int
typeof(x.u36): unsigned long long int
typeof(x.u37): unsigned long long int
typeof(x.u38): unsigned long long int
typeof(x.u39): unsigned long long int
typeof(x.u40): unsigned long long int
typeof(x.u41): unsigned long long int
typeof(x.u42): unsigned long long int
typeof(x.u43): unsigned long long int
typeof(x.u44): unsigned long long int
typeof(x.u45): unsigned long long int
typeof(x.u45): unsigned long long int
typeof(x.u46): unsigned long long int
typeof(x.u47): unsigned long long int
typeof(x.u48): unsigned long long int
typeof(x.u49): unsigned long long int
typeof(x.u50): unsigned long long int
typeof(x.u51): unsigned long long int
typeof(x.u52): unsigned long long int
typeof(x.u53): unsigned long long int
typeof(x.u54): unsigned long long int
typeof(x.u55): unsigned long long int
typeof(x.u56): unsigned long long int
typeof(x.u57): unsigned long long int
typeof(x.u58): unsigned long long int
typeof(x.u59): unsigned long long int
typeof(x.u60): unsigned long long int
typeof(x.u61): unsigned long long int
typeof(x.u62): unsigned long long int
typeof(x.u63): unsigned long long int
typeof(x.u64): unsigned long long int
```

All bit-fields seem to have the defined type rather than a type specific for the defined width.

Here is the program's output compiled with 64-bit gcc:

```
typestr(x.s1): other
typestr(x.s2): other
typestr(x.s3): other
typestr(x.s4): other
typestr(x.s5): other
typestr(x.s6): other
typestr(x.s7): other
typestr(x.s8): signed char
typestr(x.s9): other
typestr(x.s10): other
typestr(x.s11): other
typestr(x.s12): other
typestr(x.s13): other
typestr(x.s14): other
typestr(x.s15): other
typestr(x.s16): short
typestr(x.s17): other
typestr(x.s18): other
typestr(x.s19): other
typestr(x.s20): other
typestr(x.s21): other
typestr(x.s22): other
typestr(x.s23): other
typestr(x.s24): other
typestr(x.s25): other
typestr(x.s26): other
typestr(x.s27): other
typestr(x.s28): other
typestr(x.s29): other
typestr(x.s30): other
typestr(x.s31): other
typestr(x.s32): int
typestr(x.s33): other
typestr(x.s34): other
typestr(x.s35): other
typestr(x.s36): other
typestr(x.s37): other
typestr(x.s38): other
typestr(x.s39): other
typestr(x.s40): other
typestr(x.s41): other
typestr(x.s42): other
typestr(x.s43): other
typestr(x.s44): other
typestr(x.s45): other
typestr(x.s46): other
typestr(x.s47): other
typestr(x.s48): other
typestr(x.s49): other
typestr(x.s50): other
typestr(x.s51): other
typestr(x.s52): other
typestr(x.s53): other
typestr(x.s54): other
typestr(x.s55): other
typestr(x.s56): other
typestr(x.s57): other
typestr(x.s58): other
typestr(x.s59): other
typestr(x.s60): other
typestr(x.s61): other
typestr(x.s62): other
typestr(x.s63): other
typestr(x.s64): long long int
typestr(x.u1): other
typestr(x.u2): other
typestr(x.u3): other
typestr(x.u4): other
typestr(x.u5): other
typestr(x.u6): other
typestr(x.u7): other
typestr(x.u8): unsigned char
typestr(x.u9): other
typestr(x.u10): other
typestr(x.u11): other
typestr(x.u12): other
typestr(x.u13): other
typestr(x.u14): other
typestr(x.u15): other
typestr(x.u16): unsigned short
typestr(x.u17): other
typestr(x.u18): other
typestr(x.u19): other
typestr(x.u20): other
typestr(x.u21): other
typestr(x.u22): other
typestr(x.u23): other
typestr(x.u24): other
typestr(x.u25): other
typestr(x.u26): other
typestr(x.u27): other
typestr(x.u28): other
typestr(x.u29): other
typestr(x.u30): other
typestr(x.u31): other
typestr(x.u32): unsigned int
typestr(x.u33): other
typestr(x.u34): other
typestr(x.u35): other
typestr(x.u36): other
typestr(x.u37): other
typestr(x.u38): other
typestr(x.u39): other
typestr(x.u40): other
typestr(x.u41): other
typestr(x.u42): other
typestr(x.u43): other
typestr(x.u44): other
typestr(x.u45): other
typestr(x.u46): other
typestr(x.u47): other
typestr(x.u48): other
typestr(x.u49): other
typestr(x.u50): other
typestr(x.u51): other
typestr(x.u52): other
typestr(x.u53): other
typestr(x.u54): other
typestr(x.u55): other
typestr(x.u56): other
typestr(x.u57): other
typestr(x.u58): other
typestr(x.u59): other
typestr(x.u60): other
typestr(x.u61): other
typestr(x.u62): other
typestr(x.u63): other
typestr(x.u64): unsigned long long int
```

Which is consistent with each width having a different type.

The expression `E1 << E2` has the type of the promoted left operand, so any width less than `INT_WIDTH` is promoted to `int` via *integer promotion* and any width greater than `INT_WIDTH` is left alone. The result of the expression should indeed be truncated to the width of the bit-field if this width is greater than `INT_WIDTH`. More precisely, it should be truncated for an unsigned type and it might be implementation defined for signed types.

The same should occur for `E1 + E2` and other arithmetic operators if `E1` or `E2` are bit-fields with a width larger than that of `int`. The operand with the smaller width is converted to the type with the larger width and the result has type type too. This very counter-intuitive behavior causing many unexpected results, may be the cause of the widespread belief that bit-fields are bogus and should be avoided.

Many compilers do not seem to follow this interpretation of the C Standard, nor is this interpretation obvious from the current wording. It would be useful to clarify the semantics of arithmetic operations involving bit-field operands in a future version of the C Standard.

Comment: I think the key term is 'integer promotions'.  The discussion of bit-fields with integer promotions (C11 [§6.3.1.1](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.1) — _If an `int` can represent all values of the original type (as restricted by the width, for a bit-field), the value is converted to an `int`; otherwise, it is converted to an `unsigned int`. These are called the integer promotions._ — [§6.3.1.8](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.8), [§6.7.2.1](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.2.1)), don't cover the case where the width of a bit-field is wider than an `int`.

Comment: It doesn't help that the standard leaves undefined (at best implementation-defined) what types are allowed for bit-fields other than `int`, `unsigned int` and `_Bool`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I agree with your reading of the Standard, but I believe it is a major problem and the C Standard should be clarified, if not changed for the C++ semantics.

Comment: "any width less than 32", "any width greater than 32" and "if this width is greater than 32" should presumably reflect the number of bits in plain `int` and not be a fixed 32.

Comment: I agree that there's a problem (of oversight) in the C standard.  There might be room to argue that since the standard doesn't sanction the use of `uint64_t` bit-fields, the standard doesn't have to say anything about them — it should be covered by the implementation's documentation of the implementation-defined parts of the behaviour of bit-fields.  In particular, just because the 52-bits of the bit-field don't fit in a (32-bit) `int` it shouldn't mean that they're scrunched into a 32-bit `unsigned int`, but that's what a literal reading of 6.3.1.1 says.

Comment: Also, if C++ has resolved 'big bit-field' issues explicitly, then C should follow that lead as closely as possible — unless there's something inherently specific to C++ about that resolution (which is not likely).

Comment: @BenVoigt: I amended the answer with `INT_WIDTH` instead of hard-coding the common but not universal 32.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: The 6.3.1.1 text does cover types wider than an `int`: “All other types are unchanged by the integer promotions.”

Comment: @chqrlieforyellowblockquotes Thanks, this is very insightful answer! I wish I could mark two answers as accepted, as it does answer my question.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be specific to gcc's 32-bit code generator in C mode:

You can compare the assembly code using [Godbolt's Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/d8s2WY)

Here is the source code for this test:

```c
#include <stdint.h>

typedef union control {
    uint64_t q;
    struct {
        uint64_t a: 1;
        uint64_t b: 1;
        uint64_t c: 1;
        uint64_t d: 1;
        uint64_t e: 1;
        uint64_t f: 1;
        uint64_t g: 4;
        uint64_t h: 1;
        uint64_t i: 1;
        uint64_t p52: 52;
    } b;
} control_t;

uint64_t test(control_t ctl) {
    return ctl.b.p52 << 12;
}
```

The output in C mode (flags `-xc -O2 -m32`)

```
test:
        push    esi
        push    ebx
        mov     ebx, DWORD PTR [esp+16]
        mov     ecx, DWORD PTR [esp+12]
        mov     esi, ebx
        shr     ebx, 12
        shr     ecx, 12
        sal     esi, 20
        mov     edx, ebx
        pop     ebx
        or      esi, ecx
        mov     eax, esi
        shld    edx, esi, 12
        pop     esi
        sal     eax, 12
        and     edx, 1048575
        ret
```

The problem is the last instruction `and edx, 1048575` that clips the 12 most significant bits.

The output in C++ mode is identical except for the last instruction:

```
test(control):
        push    esi
        push    ebx
        mov     ebx, DWORD PTR [esp+16]
        mov     ecx, DWORD PTR [esp+12]
        mov     esi, ebx
        shr     ebx, 12
        shr     ecx, 12
        sal     esi, 20
        mov     edx, ebx
        pop     ebx
        or      esi, ecx
        mov     eax, esi
        shld    edx, esi, 12
        pop     esi
        sal     eax, 12
        ret
```

The output in 64-bit mode is much simpler and correct, yet different for the C and C++ compilers:

```
#C code:
test:
        movabs  rax, 4503599627366400
        and     rax, rdi
        ret

# C++ code:
test(control):
        mov     rax, rdi
        and     rax, -4096
        ret
```

You should file a bug report on the gcc bug tracker.

Comment: My experiments were only for 64-bit targets, but your 32-bit case is even more bisarre. I guess a bug report is due. First, I need to recheck it on a latest GCC version available to me.

Comment: @GrigoryRechistov Given the wording in [the C standard](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.7p4), the bug may very well be the 64-bit target **failing** to truncate the result down to 52 bits.  I personally would view it that way.