# C arithmetic conversion multiplying unsigned with signed and result in float

Tags: c

```
int main()
{
    printf("Hello World\n");
    int x = -10;
    unsigned y = 25;
    float z = x*y;
    printf("x=%d,y=%u,z=%f\n",x,y,z);
    return 0;
}
```

When I run the above code, I get the following output:

> Hello World
> x=-10,y=25,z=4294967046.000000

My question is:
For the second printf, I would have expected `z=(float) ( (unsigned)(-10)*25 ) = (float) (4294967286 x 25) = (float) 107374182150`, what am I missing here?

Comment: is your `unsigned` an int, float or what data type does it follow?

Comment: in that case u should put `unsigned int` since it's a discrete positive value

Comment: @TechGeek49: the `unsigned` *specifier* becomes an `unsigned int` *type.* See C11 6.7.2 for details.

Comment: I see. Is that the actual way or putting as `unsigned int` more appropriate as I've implemented in C++, Java etc

Comment: Answered here: [Signed to unsigned conversion in C - is it always safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50605/signed-to-unsigned-conversion-in-c-is-it-always-safe)

Comment: @TechGeek49: I prefer the more explicit `unsigned int` myself but there is a disconnect between type specifiers and types.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's what's happening. As per `C11 6.3.1.8 Usual arithmetic conversions` (the "otherwise" comes into play here since previous paragraphs discuss what happens when either type is already floating point):

> Otherwise, if the operand that has unsigned integer type has rank greater or equal to the rank of the type of the other operand, then the operand with signed integer type is converted to the type of the operand with unsigned integer type.

This means your signed value of `-10` becomes an unsigned value of `0xffff'fff6`, or `4,294,967,286`. Multiplying that by `25` gives `107,374,182,150` or `0x18'ffff'ff06` (which is the result you want).

However, at this point, no `float` calculations have been done, the multiplication is a pure integer calculation and the resultant value will be an integer. And that, combined with the fact your unsigned integers are 32 bits long, means it gets truncated to `0xffff'ff06`, or `4,294,967,046`.

Then you put *that* into the `float`.

---

To fix this to match your expected results, you should change he expression to force this:

```
float z = 1.0f * (unsigned)x * y;
```

This changes the `int * unsigned-int` calculation into a `float * unsigned-int * unsigned-int` one. The `unsigned` cast first ensures `x` will be converted to the equivalent unsigned value and the multiplication by `1.0f` ensures the multiplication are done in the `float` arena to avoid integer truncation.

Comment: I gave an upvote coz I find it useful albeit I prefer using explicit declaration of `unsigned`

Answer (score 3):

Following on from the correct answer from [@paxdiablo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14860/paxdiablo), the starting point for the result is due to `unsigned` having a *rank* equal to the rank of the `int`, e,g,

> The rank of any unsigned integer type shall equal the rank of the
> corresponding signed integer type, if any.  [C11 Standard - 6.3.1
> Arithmetic
> operands(p1)](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.1p1)

This comes into play with the integer conversion cited in @paxdiablo's answer:

[6.3.1.8 Usual arithmetic conversions](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.8p1)

- Otherwise, the integer promotions are performed on both operands. Then the following rules are applied to the promoted operands:

  - Otherwise, if the operand that has unsigned integer type has rank greater or equal to the rank of the type of the other operand, then the operand with signed integer type is converted to the type of the operand with unsigned integer type.

The problem is that `-10` (negative values) are stored (in almost all computers) in *two-complement*. In two's complement the value for `-10` takes the bitwise NOT of `10` and adds `1` (so in binary `00001010` become `11110110` sign extended to 32-bits). That is:

```
11111111111111111111111111110110
```

For which the `unsigned` values is `4294967286`. When multiplied by `25`, it exceeds the range of `unsigned` so the value is reduced modulo until it fits within the range of `unsigned` resulting in `4294967046`. [6.2.5 Types(p9)](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.5p9).

*What Am I Missing?*

The part that is missing is understanding the result of `unsigned` multiplication is being assigned as a float value. The intermediate result from `x * y` is `unsigned`. `float f = x * y;` is just an assignment of the result to a `float`.

What you want is for the intermediate calculation to be done as a `float`, so cast one of the operands (not the result) to `float`, e.g.

```
float f = (float)x * y
```

It does not matter which of the two values is cast to `float`, the following would be just fine:

```
float f = x * (float)y;
```

Now the result will be `-250`.

Comment: Just one minor nitpick, David, I *think* (though I could be wrong) it's complement (as in complementary) rather than compliment (as in "you look good today"). And moves are afoot in both ISO C and C++, to bless the two's complement method as the *only* signed encoding scheme going forward.

Comment: Well, you do look good today -- but you are also right there -- spell check didn't save me.. Will fix.

Comment: Thanks @DavidC.Rankin for chiming in. The part that i missed (overlooked) was that 32-bit mult has 32-bit output (unsigned wrapped around till it fits in as you mentioned).

Comment: Glad it helped. There is a lot there, and it takes going back to the standard a number of times to cement it -- and even then you will end up making trips back to the standard -- just to make sure `:)`