# why this sizeof(int) program prints out false on running?

Tags: c, sizeof

```
int main()
{
   if(sizeof(int)>-1)
   printf("true");
   else 
   printf("False");
   
   return 0;
}
```

This Programm While Running Prints Out "False". Why Does This Happen?
Even though it's Size was 4?

Comment: type promotion duplicate

Comment: `sizeof`returns an `unsigned`value and `-1`is `signed`

Comment: even though i put a positive integer there then also it prints out FALSE

Comment: better show the code

Comment: oops sry this is working now . after putting a positive integer it is printing True

Comment: Duplicate: [Implicit type promotion rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46073295/implicit-type-promotion-rules). I won't close vote since I'm partial. What you should look for specifically, is "the usual arithmetic conversions".

Answer (score 2):

the result of sizeof() is unsigned value while the right side of the comparison is signed. The compiler will convert the right side into unsigned (a very big number) first, then compare.

Comment: why the negative number will have a very big value and how it will have that value? i mean any rule or process?

Comment: @SatyabrataKar This link will help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/50632/5644356