# Why `-1 + unsigned(0) > 0` in C++?

Tags: c++, c++17, clang, unsigned, unsigned-integer

The following code output `-1 1` in C++.

If `i` is evaluated as -1, why is it larger than 0?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  auto i = -1 + unsigned(0);
  printf("%d %d\n", i, i > 0);
}
```

Comment: Use `std::cout`, then you won't risk guessing types wrong for format specifiers.

Comment: "_If i is evaluated as -1_": It is not. Your `printf` is just wrong. Avoid using it when writing C++. There is `std::cout <<` instead and since C++20 also `std::format`. First ask yourself what type `auto` in `auto i` deduces to. You can verify your guess by using `static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(i), /*guess*/>);`.

Comment: Per the [first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50632): _"In your case, we have one unsigned int and signed int. Referring to (3) above, since both operands have the same rank, [...] will need to be converted an unsigned integer."_

Comment: Using `printf` in C++ code always ends in tears.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If i is evaluated as -1

Thats a wrong premise.

`i` is not `-1`. Adding `0u` (or `unsigned(0)`) to `-1` results in an `unsigned`. You may see `-1` as output for `i` because using the wrong format specifier with `printf` is undefined.

This

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  auto i = -1 + unsigned(0);
  std::cout << i << " " << (i>0);
}
```

does not rely on guessing the type of `i` and prints:

```
4294967295 1
```

`unsigned(-1)` is the largest unsigned integer representable as `unsigned`.