# can 'fast' type prevent conversion from int to uint?

Tags: c, type-conversion, signed, stdint

Consider the following [program](https://onlinegdb.com/eT6QZaRSz):

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main()
{
    uint16_t result;
    uint16_t ui = 1;
    int16_t si = -1;
    
    result = si * ui;
    
    printf("%i", result);

    return 0;
}
```

This prints the value 65535, which is what I expect after having read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50605/signed-to-unsigned-conversion-in-c-is-it-always-safe): `si` is converted to `ui`, so max+1 is added to it. Now, in the [next code snippet](https://onlinegdb.com/b3zLxx64l), I change the type of result to `uint_fast16_t`.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main()
{
    uint_fast16_t result;
    uint16_t ui = 1;
    int16_t si = -1;
    
    result = si * ui;
    
    printf("%li", result);

    return 0;
}
```

Now, the result is `-1`. What happens here? How can the result be signed?

Comment: `printf("%li", result);` is expecting a `long` type argument, and does as what it is told: the bit pattern passed is treated as signed. If you pass an `unsigned long` value `0xFFFFFFFF` (32 bit long) that too will output `-1`.

Comment: If `uint_fast16_t` is `unsigned long`, then you're using the wrong format specifier to print it.  The `%li` format expects a signed long.  Change it to `%lu`, which expects an unsigned long.

Comment: Think about    `printf("%zu", sizeof(result));`  https://godbolt.org/z/KnMaxGz8b

Comment: Please note that the included `<stdint.h>` header defines the correct format macro constants: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer

Comment: My answer have some problem, please you accept @Lundin answer. I will delete my answer.

Comment: Your explanation of the first code is incorrect. "si is converted to ui" is nonsense as you cannot convert to a variable.  What actually happens is `si` and `ui` are both promoted to `int`. The result of the multiplication is `-1`. Then when you assign `-1` to `uint16_t result`, the converted value is `65535` . Also you cause undefined behaviour by using the wrong format specifier to print `result` in both cases

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please see below code(As @Tom Karzes said that `uint_fast16_t may be an ordinary unsigned int on some systems. In that case, %lu would be the wrong format.` And @bolov said that should use `printf("%" PRIuFAST16 "\n", result);` and `printf("%" PRIdFAST16 "\n", (int_fast16_t) result);` So I changed my answer):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>


int main()
{
    uint_fast16_t result;
    uint16_t ui = 1;
    int16_t si = -1;
    
    result = si * ui;
    printf("sizeof(result) is %zu\n", sizeof(result));

    printf("%" PRIuFAST16 "\n", result);
    printf("%" PRIdFAST16 "\n", (int_fast16_t) result);

    return 0;
}
```

Run it will output(on 64-bit computer):

```
sizeof(result) is 8
18446744073709551615
-1
```

Why output is different for the same `result`? One is `%PRIuFAST16`, other is `%PRIdFAST16`.

It's because it depend on how you see it, as `unsigned` or `signed`.

Comment: `"%lu"` is not always the correct format specifier for `uint_fast16_t`

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 Such as?

Comment: @Tom `uint_fast16_t` is only guaranteed to be a fast unsigned integer type of at least 16 bits.  There is no guarantee that it's the same size as a long.  If there were, then there wouldn't be any point to having the type in the first place.  For example, `uint_fast16_t` may be an ordinary `unsigned int` on some systems.  In that case, `%lu` would be the wrong format.

Comment: @TomKarzes  My example mainly `exhibit` for same value print different output with `unsigned` or `signed`, that is important point.(As I said `on 64-bit computer`). I will changed my answer according to you said. Thank you.

Comment: for printing fixed width integer types you should use the PRI macros from  [`<inttypes.h>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer) : `printf("%" PRIuFAST16 "\n", result);`

Comment: @Tom Keep in mind that `int` need not be 4 bytes and `long` need not be 8 bytes.  Again, it's system-specific.

Comment: @bolov Thank you for you explain, how about my updated answer?

Comment: @TomKarzes Yes, you are right, I changed my answer, how about my updated answer?

Comment: @Tom You're still making assumptions that aren't required by the language.  What if an `int` is 2 bytes?  What if an `int` is 8 bytes?  It will fail in both cases.  It would make more sense to do `if sizeof(result) <= sizeof(int)` etc.  Also, there's no `else` so if neither test succeeds, your code silently does nothing.  It would be better to give an error.

Comment: @TomKarzes I'm sorry, my native language is not English. About `aren't required by the language`, I can't understand well, can you speak more details? I know now usually sizeof(int) is 4 bytes , but before in some platform sizeof(int) may be 2 bytes. As `What if an int is 2 bytes? What if an int is 8 bytes?`, so I let sizeof(result) compare with 4, why I chioce 4, because usually sizeof(int) is 4 bytes, sure it may be not accurate. As `It will fail in both cases`, when will fail in both cases? I think sizeof(result) either greater than sizeof(int)(may be equal to) or less than sizeof(int).

Comment: @TomKarzes About `What if an int is 8 bytes?`, I see a book named `Computer Systems A programmer's Perspective(Third Edition)` at `Chapter 2.1.2 Data Sizes` say size of `int` is both 4 in 32-bit computer and 64-bit computer.

Comment: I gave you the correct way to print. Your `if` / `else` shenanigans are not the way to go.

Comment: @bolov I'm sorry, my native language is not English. Before I learn c programming with Chinese book, I'm not doing shenanigans, now answer is according to my understand, maybe my understanding is wrong, before I never see `PRIuFAST16`,  in order to avoid say I shenanigans, please you correct my answer.

Comment: @bolov please see my comment at original problem below.

Comment: `uint_fast16_t` is a type alias. Depending on the platform it can be `unsigned char` (very uncommon, but technically possible), `unsigned short`, `unsigned int`, `unsigned long` or `unsigned long long`. Therefore for a correct cross platform solution you cannot use `u` or `lu` specifiers for `printf`. `PRIuFAST16` is a macro defined in the `inttypes.h` header that expands on the correct specifier.

Comment: The correct way to print a `uint_fast16_t` variable is `printf("%" PRIuFAST16 "\n", result);` For example on a platform where `uint_fast16_t` is `unsigned int` this expands to `printf("%" "u" "\n", result);`. In C adjacent string literals are concatenated so this in turn is converted to `printf("%u\n", result);`.

Comment: I am happy to answer more questions if you have them.

Comment: @bolov Thank you for you explain, I learn it that before I never meet. As you said `it can be unsigned char (very uncommon, but technically possible), unsigned short, unsigned int, unsigned long or unsigned long long`, it means that maybe `sizeof(result)` is 1 or 2 or 4 or 8, but when I want to show value of `result` with  `signed` type, how can I print it correctly?

Comment: In the header I linked there are all the PRI macros that cover all the aliases.

Comment: @bolov I changed my answer, Is that right? But I don't understand why use such as `PRIuFASTx` or `PRIdFASTx`, I know here x is 16, because OP use `uint_fast16_t result;`

Comment: `printf("%" PRIdFAST16 "\n", result);` this is incorrect because `result` is unsigned. You have to cast `result` first: `printf("%" PRIdFAST16 "\n", (int_fast16_t) result);`

Comment: @bolov Thank you for your patience in explaining, I have changed my answer, thank you very much.

Answer (score 6):

> si is converted to ui

Maybe or maybe not, depends on the system. You might be making an over-simplification here and cutting corners when trying to understand this. Check out [Implicit type promotion rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46073295/implicit-type-promotion-rules) regarding the `si * u1` expression.

- On 8/16 bit systems with 16 bit `int`, then in `si * ui` the signed operand is converted as per "the usual arithmetic conversions" to `unsigned int`.
- On 32/64 bit systems with 32 bit `int`, then in `si * ui` both operands are converted to `int` which is signed 32. The result of the operation is `-1`. You then store this in an unsigned type in the next step and then the signed integer is converted to an unsigned type.

Furthermore, `printf` might make an internal conversion if you lie to it and pass a type which doesn't match the conversion specifier. The correct format for these types are:

```c
#include <inttypes.h>

printf("%"PRIu16 "\n", x);     // for uint16_t
printf("%"PRIuFAST16 "\n", x); // for uint_fast16_t
```

---

So what happened when you changed to a "fast" type? Very likely `uint_fast16_t` was replaced with a 32 or 64 bit integer type. In which case `result = si * ui;` goes like:

- Integer promote both of `si` and `ui` to `int`.
- Calculate the result, it is `-1`.
- Store the result in a large unsigned type - we get a conversion to a large unsigned number. A so called "sign extension" likely happens here.
- Then you lie to `printf` and tell it to read the large unsigned number as `signed long` even though it is not. This is strictly speaking undefined behavior (wrong conversion specifier), but in practice it seems an implementation-defined conversion from a large unsigned integer to signed `long` took place inside printf.

Example tried on x86_64 Linux:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int main(void)
{
    uint_fast16_t result;
    uint16_t ui = 1;
    int16_t si = -1;
    
    result = si * ui;
    
    printf("result is %zu bytes\n",sizeof(result));
    printf("result has value %"PRIuFAST16 "\n", result);
    printf("result converted to long: %ld\n", (long)result);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
result is 8 bytes
result has value 18446744073709551615
result converted to long: -1
```

And this is just because `long` happened to be an 8 byte type too on my system.